# cookie trouble with logging into google voice with php and curl?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to google voice using curl and google voice class at https://github.com/aaronpk/Google-Voice-PHP-API , to send a sms .

I am getting the following error: “Your browser’s cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on. [?]”

The root of the problem during login is in the following code:

```
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=grandcentral');
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->_cookieFile);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'Email' => $this->_login,
        'Passwd' => $this->_pass,
        'continue' => 'https://www.google.com/voice/account/signin',
        'service' => 'grandcentral',
        'GALX' => $GALX
        ));

    $html = curl_exec($this->_ch);
```

Can anyone advise me on what to do?

Thanks in advance,

KC

Comment: WHat happens if you also define `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` as the same file?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it Wrikken, I added `  curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->_cookieFile);`, but nothing has changed. I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Hm, and you are definitly using the same instance of the class? Could you examine / provide the (anonmized) request & response headers?

Comment: request headers: string 'POST /accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=grandcentral HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)

Host: www.google.com

Accept: */*

Cookie: GAPS=1:gBWsvwHhkE4b0AtyVuLjgtQBtW6ISQ:AG59bxV-tUeFug5t
Content-Length: 627
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------b658d42214be
' (length=357)

Comment: response headers: html HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Set-Cookie: GAPS=1:xdkKXeIlul2f9b7Mi-zKQwdnsOn3RA:8kIbvQ3C3_Ks52dV;Path=/accounts;Expires=Sun, 12-Jan-2014 03:51:58 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly Date: Fri, 13 Jan 2012 03:51:58 GMT Expires: Fri, 13 Jan 2012 03:51:58 GMT Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Content-Length: 1886 Server: GSE

Comment: On a subsequent request (the next one), does it a request send the _new_ cookie string or the old one?

Comment: Thank you Wrikken, I think they are different cookies ( if I am doing this right ). The first time I run it I get: GAPS=1:egqvsWe6BwLsIjaabXTs8sQBxvnPYA:z3XsoEGtmZ7kLo1c
The second time I run I get: Cookie: GAPS=1:onRkZ0rAOAM-kaNDYJ9zuL1SYp2LQA:HF94TjP9dV936Pdv

Comment: After looking at this again, I need to make a correction. There are 2 parts to the code. 1) where CURL calls up the initial login page for google voice (https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?passive=true&service=grandcentral) and parse the headers. I did not show this but it is at https://github.com/aaronpk/Google-Voice-PHP-API . the class then attempts to parse the response headers , and then 2) executes a post ( shown above )

Comment: request headers for part 1): 'request_header' => string 'GET /ServiceLogin?passive=true&service=grandcentral HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)

Host: accounts.google.com

Accept: */*

Comment: response headers for part 1): HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&service=grandcentral Content-Length: 260 Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2012 04:04:09 GMT Expires: Sun, 15 Jan 2012 04:04:09 GMT Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains Set-Cookie: GAPS=1:DtnZZNU_nV7bMO5deBV8NZt608nP3Q:etGbLtV12zHlHzQf;Path=/;Expires=Tue, 14-Jan-2014 04:04:09 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly Set-Cookie: GALX=Lc8kkYp5w1Y;Path=/;Secure Cache-control: no-cache, no-store Pragma: no-cache Expires: Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT X-Frame-Options: Deny X-Auto-Login: realm=com.google&args=service%3Dgrandcentral%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.google.com%252FManageAccount Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2012 04:04:09 GMT ...

Comment: I'm not experienced with cookies but it appears that there are 2: GAPS and GALX. does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem.You do the Get request with cookie enabled.use that cookie while POST too.it works fine.